# Symmetric set difference is equivalent to proper set difference and what?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to see if some set operations can be represented by some other set operations.

proper set difference + finite union $\implies$ symmetric set difference $\implies$ proper set difference + finite disjoint union

The first $\implies$:
$A$ symminus $B$ = [($A$ $\cup$ $B$) properminus $A$] $\cup$ [($A$ $\cup$ $B$) properminus $B$]

The second $\implies$ is trivial.

So I was wondering "symmetric set difference $\iff$  proper set difference + what set operation"?

Note  $A$ properminus $B$ is defined as $A \setminus B$ for $B \subseteq A$.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What do you mean by $+$, $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ here?

Comment: @RahulNarain: I would like to see if some set operations can be represented by some other set operations.

Comment: To make sure that I understand: when you write $\oplus+\otimes\implies\circ$ you mean that $\circ$ can be defined in terms of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes!

Comment: Ah, and by $\ominus \Rightarrow \setminus + \sqcup$ you mean both $\ominus \Rightarrow \setminus$ and $\ominus \Rightarrow \sqcup$ independently.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Yes!

Comment: That last edit helps enormously: after making my mistake a minute ago I was wondering how you got $A\setminus B$ out of symmetric difference!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Sorry for the confusion. I am not sure if that is called proper set difference by mathematicians?

Comment: I don’t think that I’ve ever seen it given a name at all.

Comment: I don't understand the "trivial" part.  It seems to me that the only binary operations you can get from the symmetric difference $\triangle$ by composition are the four operations mapping the pair $(A,B)$ to $\emptyset$, $A$, $B$, and $A \mathbin{\triangle} B$ respectively.  I say this because $\triangle$ is associative and commutative, so all we can get is $(A \mathbin{\triangle} \cdots \mathbin{\triangle} A) \mathbin{\triangle} (B \mathbin{\triangle}\cdots \mathbin{\triangle} B)$ for some numbers of copies of $A$ and $B$, and it only matters whether these numbers are even or odd.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: The trivial part: a proper set difference between $A$ and $B$ is only for $B \subseteq A$, it is exactly $A △ B$. A pairwise disjoint union between  $A$ and $B$ is only for $A \cap B = \emptyset$, it is exactly $A △ B$. BTW: in your comment $A △ A$  is $\emptyset$ and $A △ A △ A$  is $A$, isn't it? Do you have some idea for the question in my post?

Comment: @Tim I see, I didn't notice the restriction on the domain of $\setminus$.  And yes, iterating $\triangle$ on $A$ gives $\emptyset, A, \emptyset, A, \ldots$.

Comment: Some of your operations have restricted domains, so to express an operation $\circ$ as the composition of other operations, do you mean that the domains of $\circ$ and the composition are equal as well?

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Each operation has its original domain. For an operation with a restricted domain, I want to accomodate it, for example, see how I accomodate proper set difference for the first =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no non-trivial way to do what the question is asking.

Let's say that a set of partial (possibly total) binary operations $S$ is *complete* for the symmetric difference operation $\triangle$ if

- every operation in $S$ is a (possibly trivial) restriction of some composition of copies of $\triangle$, and
- for every pair of sets $(A,B)$ there is a partial operation $\cdot$ that is a composition of partial operations in $S$ and has the property that $A \cdot B$ is defined and is equal to $A \mathbin{\triangle} B$.  (Note that is weaker than saying that $S$ itself is a composition of partial operations in $S$, which is impossible if none of the operations in $S$ is total.)

Even with this weak version of the definition, the only sets $S$ that are complete for $\triangle$ are trivial, in a sense that we will make precise below.  Note that by the first clause of the definition, and the fact that $\triangle$ is commutative, associative, and satisfies $A \mathbin{\triangle} A = \emptyset$, every partial  operation $\cdot$ in $S$ is the restriction of one of the four following total operations:

- The constant binary operation given by $A \cdot B = \emptyset$,
- The projection given by $A \cdot B = A$,
- The projection given by $A \cdot B = B$, and
- The symmetric difference operation $\triangle$ itself.

The first three operations do not help us form any additional binary operations under composition, so we consider them to be trivial, and we assume that $S$ consists only of restrictions of $\triangle$.

A trivial way to get a complete set $S$ is for the union of the domains of the partial operations in $S$ to consist of *all* pairs $(A,B)$: for example, the proper set difference operation "$\setminus$" as defined in the question is simply the restriction of $\triangle$ to the domain $\{(A,B) : B \subseteq A\}$, so we could let $S = \{\setminus, \cdot\}$ where $\cdot$ is the restriction of $\triangle$ to the complementary domain $\{(A,B) : B \not \subseteq A\}$.  More generally, we could weaken the triviality requirement to consider the domains of the partial operations in $S$ *and their reverses*; for example, this requirement would be satisfied by the set $S = \{\setminus, \cdot\}$ where $\cdot$ now denotes the restriction of $\triangle$ to the domain $\{(A,B) : A \not \subseteq B\}$.

However, *every* complete set is trivial in this way.  Suppose that some pair $(A,B)$ is not in the domain of any partial operation $\cdot$ in $S$, and neither is the reversed pair $(B,A)$.  Because the partial operations in $S$ are all binary, it is not hard to show that the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ cannot be in the domain of any *composition* of elements of $S$ either, so there is no way to get the symmetric difference $A \mathbin{\triangle} B$.